# Ideas for Powers in my Magic System

Tags: magic

My magic system is based on amplifying the effects of the fight or flight response by people powering stimulators they are naturally born with. These stimulators stimulate the amygdala.
These stimulators are powered by magic that can be created within and each stimulator amplifies a different effect of the fight or flight response. One chooses which stimulator they want to power based on their situation, directing the magic they create to the desired stimulator.

All I can think of from a power system like this is strengthening muscles or improving senses, does anyone have other ideas for powers?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Did you know? Fear/fight or flight responses actually tends to reduce our overall senses, rather than improving them. Indeed, instead of trying to make out events 360° in our environment, one will focus solely on the main threat to better fight it. Or flee from it. A bit like sprinting which narrows our sight to the path we take.

Comment: As for your question : Can you give some context of your world, or what you are trying to achieve within it? The skills needed will be vastly different if you're an hacking agent who needs solid nerves and concentration vs a primitive man who'd need more raw power to wrestle with that mammoth over there :p. This site is better at solving specific and detailed problems than to gather ideas around ^^.

Comment: If fight or flight leaves you with few options for good powers, maybe start with lots of powers you have ideas for, then back into the reason for those powers second.  If you are digging fight or flight, have that be one of the powers.

Comment: @Tortliena my bad, I thought fight or flight improves senses, maybe I'll change one of the powers to strengthening focus on a threat.

Comment: @Tortliena as for my world, enhancing the effects of the fight or flight response is my explanation for why people in my world can momentarily show unrealistic feats of strength .  I mainly wanted to show these enhancements being used when people are fighting each other in close combat. I was also thinking this can be how my world's militaries fight rather than using conventional weapons.

Comment: @Lilbrony21 [Can you add these intentions to your question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/posts/230965/edit) (the edit button is at the bottom of your question)? Also, if you happen to have an idea of what your world is, technologically speaking, it could help (is it medieval-fantasy? Cyberpunk? Sci-fi? Modern?...)

Answer (score 2):

**Nothing Superhuman**

All your magic system does is modify brain chemistry. It cannot produce any *superhuman* effects.

You cannot modify someone's instincts to make them lift a boulder or run at 100 miles an hour. There are indeed urban legends of mothers tipping over cars and fighting bears to protect their children. But many of these stories are exaggerated to make them more entertaining.

The most you can hope is to achieve a period of extreme energy and endurance, where the person performs slightly above normal for an elevated period. Perhaps with none or minimal sleep.

The person whose *flight* instinct is kicked into overdrive  still cannot run 100 mph. But they can run full speed for three times as long as normal.
The person whose *fight* instinct is kicked still cannot lift a boulder. But they can shift bags of potatoes from morning till night.

Consider researching [mania](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mania) which is where brain chemistry leads to periods of extreme energy. In any case you should expect the period of enhanced performance to be followed by a period of exhaustion and depression.

After walking for 100 miles without sleep the person then falls down and sleeps for three days. After shifting potatoes all day and night the person wakes up the following morning with aching bones and joints.

You can also get effects that are clearly psychological. For example a platoon of soldiers that fights to the death rather than fleeing -- but they are not any stronger or faster than normal. Or someone who throws their own body in between two gears of a giant machine to clog it up at the cost of their own life. Likewise you could cast a spell to make the enemy flee even though they were winning.

All else being equal, this "Cause fear" is the most powerful spell in your magic system for combat.

I do not see magic replacing conventional weapons. But the psychological effects would be useful in tandem with shooting them with bullets.

Comment: Actually the (partially) lifting boulders or cars part is true. However it comes at a cost. Your larger muscle groups are well capable of ripping the bone where the tendons enter it, but neurological limits prevent that (just like you feel you cant hold on to something burning hot for a short while unless your life depends on it). In fight/fright mode those limits can sometimes be lifted. Just be assured that you'll need weeks to months of recuperation afterwards depending on how much damage you'll do to yourself. But damage IS guaranteed.